# Merging (adding) pandas column data using column name based on other columns contents (opposite direction values)

Tags: python, pandas, merge, where-clause, mask

I have a pandas dataframe that contains link information based on nodes and links ending at particular node.
To this information I would like to add information about links in opposite direction.
Dataframe looks like this (just a sample):

```
    atNode  l1no    l1ln    l2no    l2ln    l3no    l3ln    l4no    l4ln    l5no    l5ln    l6no    l6ln
0   10000   10180   2       10046   1       10183   2       0       0       0       0       0       0
1   10001   10131   2       10003   1       10188   2       0       0       0       0       0       0
2   10002   10188   2       10005   1       10130   2       0       0       0       0       0       0
8   10009   10131   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
13  10046   10000   1       10317   2       10222   1       10346   2       0       0       0       0
30  10131   10138   0       10009   2       10415   2       10001   2       0       0       0       0
66  10180   10000   2       10032   2       10221   1       0       0       0       0       0       0
72  10188   10001   1       10002   1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
```

What I'd like to get is: 6 additional columns (`l1op`, `l2op`, ...`l6op`) with value `l`**X**`ln`, but for opposite direction (like: `l1no` = `atNode` , `atNode` = `l1no`)
I mean here: for the first row I'd like to have `l1op` = 2 (from row 66), `l2op` = 1 (from row 13), etc...

I guess main problem here is making a map(mask?) what index include `atNode` value form l**X**no column, then find what column l**Y**no has `atNode` (from l**X**no), and then... use l**Y**ln as l**X**op .

I could probably make 6 loops (for max 6 links at each node) and merge data, column by column, but (it would be slow and) I think there is more "Pythonic" way to do this, I was thinking about using `map`, `mask`, `where`... but I'm not experienced enough to make it work that way.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**: Thanks to ***Shubham Sharma*** I was able to figure out something like this (using `max()` function):

```py
      for i in range (1,7):
            s1 = df.set_index(['atNode', f'l{i}no'])
            df[f'l{i}op'] = np.nan
            for j in range (1,7):
                s2 = df.set_index(['atNode', f'l{j}no'])
                s2 = s2.swaplevel()
                df['tmp'] = s1.index.map(s2[f'l{j}ln'])
                df[f'l{i}op'] = df[[f'l{i}op', 'tmp']].max(axis=1)
      df= df.drop('tmp', axis=1)
```

It's not perfect but it's working, but any sophisticated upgrades would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

For each `lxno` column set the column as an index of dataframe along with `atnode`, then swap levels to create anouther dataframe with reverted index. Then use multindex map to yank the values from `lxln` column and assign it to `lxop`

```
for i in range(1, 7):
    s1 = df.set_index(['atNode', f'l{i}no'])
    s2 = s1.swaplevel()

    df[f'l{i}op'] = s1.index.map(s2[f'l{i}ln'])
```

---

```
    atNode   l1no  l1ln   l2no  l2ln   l3no  l3ln   l4no  l4ln  l5no  l5ln  l6no  l6ln  l1op  l2op  l3op  l4op  l5op  l6op
0    10000  10180     2  10046     1  10183     2      0     0     0     0     0     0   2.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
1    10001  10131     2  10003     1  10188     2      0     0     0     0     0     0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2    10002  10188     2  10005     1  10130     2      0     0     0     0     0     0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
8    10009  10131     0      0     0      0     0      0     0     0     0     0     0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
13   10046  10000     1  10317     2  10222     1  10346     2     0     0     0     0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
30   10131  10138     0  10009     2  10415     2  10001     2     0     0     0     0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
66   10180  10000     2  10032     2  10221     1      0     0     0     0     0     0   2.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
72   10188  10001     1  10002     1      0     0      0     0     0     0     0     0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: It works for many pairs, but not all. I was thinking about splitting the table for each pair, but swappable pairs of indexes are so much better, I just have to investigate why some pairs doesn't have opposite value (while they should have).

Comment: There is something not working here, hard to tell why. As you may notice l1op in row with index 1 should have value 2 (based on row 30) but is NaN. There are few values found but there is a lot too many NaN (while there should be numbers found).

Comment: I think the solution is working as per your requirements, If you see in row with index 1 (atNode, l1n) is (10001, 10131) while at index 30 it is (10131, 10138) so there is no match hence the null value

Comment: yeah, but also at row 30 atNode=10131 and l4no=10001 (with l4ln=2) so in row with index 1 opposite to 1000-10131 should be l1op=2... (There is something with multindex or rather not finding the data with mapped multindex).